# How to make the AppBar AND table's headers sticky (so stacked under each other) on the same page when scrolling, using Material UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Here's the AppBar and the Table's screenshots:

[This is the screenshot at the top of the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1qwg.jpg)

[This is the screenshot once you start scrolling down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMlAE.jpg)

Here's the code for the AppBar and the Table:

```
 <AppBar position="static" style = {{background : "#00009A"}}>
          <Toolbar>
          <Link to="/view" className={classes.navLink} align = 'left'>
            <Box textAlign = "left" >
          <Typography variant="h6" flex={1} align = 'left'>
            APP TITLE
          </Typography>
          </Box>
          </Link>

          <Link to="/view" className={classes.navLink}>
            <Button color="inherit" align='left' }>Map Skills</Button>
          </Link>
</AppBar>

<Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table" style={{ marginTop: 20, marginBottom: 30 }}>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          {columns.map(column => (
            <TableCell
              key={column.id}
              align={column.align}
              style={{ width: column.minWidth, fontWeight: 500, fontSize: 17, backgroundColor: "#C1D8F7"}}
            >
              {column.label === "" ? props.heading : column.label}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
```

I've tried to make the AppBar's "**position = 'fixed'** " but that just overlapped the table's header when scrolling down.

I've also tried playing around with zIndex to move stuff to the front or back.

I need them to be both stacked under each other when scrolling, instead of overlap. 
But i think that table header's sticky header always sticks to the top of the page.

Any solutions would be of great help! Thanks!

Comment: any luck with this ? i am facing the same issue and didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Make the AppBar `position="fixed"`, the table header `paddingTop: "68px"`, Table `stickyHeader`, and get rid of any `overflow: 'auto'`.

```
<AppBar position="fixed" color="primary">
  <Toolbar>
  <IconButton color="secondary">
    <FilterListRounded />
  </IconButton>
  <Typography variant="h6">App Title</Typography>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

...

```
const StyledTableCell = withStyles(() => ({
  head: {
    paddingTop: "68px",
  },
}))(TableCell);
```

...

```
<Table size="small" stickyHeader>
  <TableHead className={classes.head}>
    <TableRow>
      <StyledTableCell>Header 1</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell>Header 2</StyledTableCell>
      <StyledTableCell>Header 3</StyledTableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    {props.results.map(row => {
      return(
        <TableRow key={row.id} hover>
          <TableCell>{row.one}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.two}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{row.three}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
    )})}
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```